# All LVM drives are active but none are mounted (ls shows Input/output error)

Tags: linux, hard-drive, lvm

I am a complete noob when it comes to LVM. I did set it up on 4 drives successfully, but I went to change one of my drives to a larger one, and now none of my drives are mounted. I have a total of 4 physical volumes, 4 volume groups, and 4 logical volumes. Since I don't need my old group, this is what I did:

```
umount /dev/VG1/LV1
dmsetup remove /dev/VG1/*
echo 1 > /sys/block/sdb/device/delete
umount /dev/sdb1
umount /dev/sdb
```

Something among those lines. That worked great and my drive was basically removed from the system. Now I remove it physically from my server, and poof none of my other drives work. If I do something like:

```
cd /mnt/LV2/
ls
```

It says:

> ls: reading directory '.': Input/output error

Here is some output that could help:

```
root@SERVER:/# vgscan
  Reading all physical volumes.  This may take a while...
  Found volume group "VG2" using metadata type lvm2
  Found volume group "VG3" using metadata type lvm2
  Found volume group "VG4" using metadata type lvm2
root@SERVER:/# lvscan
  ACTIVE            '/dev/VG2/LV2' [<931.51 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/VG3/LV3' [<931.51 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/VG4/LV4' [1.36 TiB] inherit
```

As you can see, all logical volumes are active. If we take a look at /etc/fstab:

```
/dev/VG2/LV2 /mnt/LV2 ext4 defaults,nofail 0 0
```

You can see it's listed there (I removed the old one). If I do:

```
mount -a
```

It's still not working. No errors or anything.

What am I doing wrong here? How do I get my data back online and mounted into the correct directories (according to /etc/fstab)?

## EDIT:

Found something weird:

```
root@SERVER:/# cd /mnt/LV2/
root@SERVER:/mnt/LV2# ls
ls: reading directory '.': Input/output error
root@SERVER:/mnt/LV2# cd Downloads/
root@SERVER:/mnt/LV2/Downloads# ls
 Directory.Name.Here
```

Why is this happening? It's mounted and there are files inside folders, but it still says Input/output error?

Comment: Have you checked dmesg?

Comment: I don't see a `vgremove` in there anywhere. `man vgremove` suggests `vgreduce --removemissing`

Comment: @Peleion Sorry, I forgot to note that one. Yeah, I did do vgremove and the volume group is completely gone.

Answer (score 0):

I know this sounds like a bad solution, but I was honestly pulling bricks out of my underwear at this point. I took a call and said `sudo reboot`.

Server booted right up and all my mounts worked perfectly. I'm glad it worked, but I have no idea why.